# Search and replace dots and commas in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': ['sku 1.1', 'sku 1.2', 'sku 1.3'], 'col2': ['9.876.543,21', 654, '321,01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

       col1           col2
0   sku 1.1   9.876.543,21
1   sku 1.2            654
2   sku 1.3         321,01
```

Data in col2 are numbers in local format, which I would like to convert into:

```
      col2
9876543.21
       654
    321.01
```

I tried `df['col2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col2'], downcast='float')`, which returns a ValueError: : Unable to parse string "9.876.543,21" at position 0.

I tried also `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))`, which returns ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.023.654.46'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The best is use if possible parameters in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

If not possible, then `replace` should help:

```
df['col2'] = (df['col2'].replace('\.','', regex=True)
                        .replace(',','.', regex=True)
                        .astype(float))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention CSV is not possible as the data is from Google Sheet.  Second solution with replace solved the problem for me. Thank you!

Comment: @andrej Glad can help!

Comment: What if I want to do the replacement in all columns in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', '&'))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('.', ','))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('&', '.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always better off using standard system facilities where they exist. Knowing that some locales use commas and decimal points differently I could not believe that Pandas would not use the formats of the locale.

Sure enough a quick search revealed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Keiku/b3e0038a2d1145ea82eda8444b98c02a), which explains how to make use of locales to convert strings to numbers. In essence you need to `import locale` and after you've built the dataframe call `locale.setlocale` to establish a locale that uses commas as decimal points and periods for separators, then apply the dataframe's `applymapp` method.