# How to convert multiple columns with european numbers (comma as decimal separator) to float?

Tags: pandas, floating-point, numbers, digit-separator

I have multiple columns that contain numbers in european format, e.g.

```
1.630,78
```

They have different chars in front or at the end (€, %) so I can't use pandas converter function.

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", decimal=',', separator={"col1": float, "col": float}
```

won't work because I have to remove the signs first which I can only do after reading in the whole file.

[Search and replace dots and commas in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088443/search-and-replace-dots-and-commas-in-pandas-dataframe/49088724#49088724)

did not work, I get a

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

but every row has an entry

How can I change those strings in specific columns then to floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the colums as strings and then use [`translate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html):

```
tt = str.maketrans(',', '.', '.€%')
df.col1 = df.col1.str.translate(tt).astype(float)
```

PS: you may need to adopt the third argument with the characters to remove as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I apply this to a list of column names I need to convert?

Comment: you can use a loop: `for c in my_col_list:` `df[c] = df[c].str.translate(tt).astype(float)`